# Почему ютобовское api конфликтует с jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, youtube-api

Есть стандартный код ютубовского api для управления ютубовским плеером(Он нужен для того чтоб видео при загрузке страницы воспроизводилось автоматически, дальше играло циклически плейлист который в массиве ) .

Но при оборачивании этого кода в функцию jquery document ready код отказывается работать. А вот когда код обернут в document onload то он работает.

Вот код :

```js
$(function() {

      var playlist = ["0Bmhjf0rKe8", "jQZtk-fCWQ4", "5wosC9QLQTM"];
      var whonext = 0;
      var player;

      function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: playlist[0],
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
        whonext++;
      }

      function playNext() {
        player.loadVideoById({
          'videoId': playlist[whonext],
          'startSeconds': 5,
          'endSeconds': 60,
          'suggestedQuality': 'large'
        });

        whonext++;
      }

      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data === 0) {
          playNext();
        }
      }

      onYouTubePlayerAPIReady();

    });
```

```html
<iframe id="player" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" title="YouTube video player" width="640" height="390" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5wosC9QLQTM?enablejsapi=1"></iframe>
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
```

Фидл для наглядности : http://jsfiddle.net/v3qzb/18/

Comment: А что не так? У меня плеер работает нормально(после добавления скобки в конце фидла).

Comment: У меня в примере все работает. Как именно он не работает у вас?

Comment: @ Baga, я фидл обновил попробуй те сейчас . Он не работает  когда есть событие ready .

Comment: @Vartlok, скобку я тоже добавил , но код не работает . Выдыет ошибку что функция не обявлена. Но когда ставлю событие не ready а OnLoad то тогда работает. Хотелось  чтоб работал при событии ready.

Comment: Сейчас YT.Player is not a function - это значит, что вы не подключили нужный JS файл. Вообще, добавьте прям в вопрос, куда нажать и что вы ожидаете при этом.

Comment: @Vartlok, Изменил вопрос.   js файл для управления api у меня подключен, и код когда обернут в  document onload либо когда он без jquery работает .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YouTube плеер грузится отдельно от остальной страницы и никак не зависит от состояния DOM. Коллбек для него отдельный и должен быть установлен в глобальном скоупе, т.е. на объект `window`. Этот колбек будет автоматически вызван, когда плеер будет готов к использованию, вам не нужно вызывать его самому:

```
window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady = function () {
    // с этого момента можно начинать использовать YT.Player
};
```

Проблема в том, чтобы синхронизировать два события - загрузки плеера и загрузки DOM - и начинать инициализацию приложения, зная что нужный DOM уже существует на странице и плеер готов к использованию. Ведь плеер может загрузится быстрее DOM и если начинать добавлять колбек для плеера внутри колбека для загрузки DOM, то ничего не сработает.

Одним из вариантов, который я когда-то использовал, это  [`jQuery.Deferred`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/). Он позволит сообщить приложению, когда плеер был загружен, независимо от момента его загрузки.

```
var YTdeferred = $.Deferred();
window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
    // как только плеер загрузился - сообщаем всем слушающим скриптам
    YTdeferred.resolve(window.YT);
};
```

Чтобы привязаться к событию загрузки плеера в jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    YTdeferred.done(function(YT) {
        // здесь мы уверены что DOM и плеер загружены, можно выполнять инициализацию
    });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо это помогло

Answer (score 2):

Я понял в чем ваша пробела, вы не понимаете разницу между onLoad и onReady для документа. [На английском SO есть хороший ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8396457/1646082). Если на русском то:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 // выполняется когда HTML-Document загружен and DOM готов
 alert("document is ready");
});    

$(window).load(function() {
 // выполняется, когда вся страница загрузится, включая iframe, объекты и картинки
 alert("window is loaded");
});
```

В вашем случае объявление YT.Player находится внутри iframe и соответственно обратиться к нему можно только полной загрузки страницы, т.е. при  `$(window).load(function() {})`. Вы же пытаетесь обратиться к этой переменной когда она еще не объявлена(до загрузки iframe) и получаете ошибку.

Comment: То есть на сколько я понял в моем случае мне поможет только On load ? ready не использовать ?

Comment: @Dementiy1999 Есть хак, вы можете руками прописать в своём коде ссылку на JS файл, где объявлен YT, но в случае если гугл поменяет имя файла у вас будут проблемы. Так что лучше использовать только load.